# trigering or duplicating tabel on mysql

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have 2 set of  mysql database they have the same database structure and same table that have different data inside.

At the moment there is one table called "memberpoint" on each database that i want to sync so that two table will have the same value every time one of them got updated

can any one help me?

note : i am using mysql 5.1.43

Comment: please share us what u have tried so far and what error you got while trying

Comment: Create a trigger on table `memberpoint` and `update/insert` based on event to `duplicate of  memberpoint` table. https://www.siteground.com/kb/mysql-triggers-use/

Comment: Bi-directional sync?

Comment: yes bi-directional...i created trigger for both table end up making an endless loop of trigger....the problem is that table A and table B are different shop i want it to be merge every time one of them got change